# ORA-00904: : invalid identifier two references in Oracle

Tags: sql

I cant find a good anwser too my question, I want to create a table that have references too one table but i use it twice in the code..

```
Vårdnadshavare VARCHAR(11), 
  FOREIGN KEY (Vårdnadshavare) REFERENCES Person(Personnummer),
Barn VARCHAR(11), 
  FOREIGN KEY (Barn) REFERENCES Person(Personnummer)
```

But then i get the error:
ORA-02256: number of referencing columns must match referenced columns

I understand that my reference is wrong some how but can´t figure it out...

Sorry for the swedish words!!

```
Create table Ärende(
  Ärendenr VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  Handläggare VARCHAR(50),  
    FOREIGN KEY (Handläggare) REFERENCES Handläggare(Anställningsnr), 
  Vårdnadshavare VARCHAR(11), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Vårdnadshavare) REFERENCES Person(Personnummer),
  Barn VARCHAR(11), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Barn) REFERENCES Person(Personnummer), 
  In Datum VARCHAR(50), 
  Ömmande Skäl VARCHAR(5), 
  Förskola VARCHAR(50), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Förskola) REFERENCES Förskola(IDnr), 
  PRIMARY KEY (Ärendenr)
);
```

I have used `Person(Personnumer)` as a reference before just not twice in createing a table..

Comment: Can you show your entire create statement?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus "Vårdnadshavare" can be translated as parent, "barn" as child, "personnummer" is a sort of social security number. Both parent and child need to have a valid one.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson K. Sorry for my swedish (?) ;) .So the problem may be the PK of Person. Is it a composite key ?

Comment: @user3356636 What are the primary keys of `Handläggare`, `Person` and `Förskola`?

Answer (score 0):

I created this script which does work. Probably there is an issue with your indexes:

```
create table handläggare
( anställningsnr varchar(50) primary key
)

create table person
( personnummer varchar(11) primary key
)
;

create table förskola
( idnr varchar(50) primary key
);

create table ärende
( ärendenr varchar(50) not null
, handläggare varchar(50)
, foreign key (handläggare) references handläggare(anställningsnr)
, vårdnadshavare varchar(11)
, foreign key (vårdnadshavare) references person(personnummer)
, barn varchar(11)
, foreign key (barn) references person(personnummer)
, indatum varchar(50)
, ömmandeskäl varchar(5)
, förskola varchar(50)
, foreign key (förskola) references förskola(idnr)
, primary key (ärendenr)
);
```

There are two other issues in your script above which I edited:

1. `In Datum` should be one name, not separated by a space;
2. `Ömmande Skäl`, same as above.

Comment: Did you have any luck testing this out? Need more help?

Answer (score 0):

In you create statement you have provided 4 referenes:

```
  Handläggare VARCHAR(50),  
    FOREIGN KEY (Handläggare) REFERENCES Handläggare(Anställningsnr), 
  Vårdnadshavare VARCHAR(11), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Vårdnadshavare) REFERENCES Person(Personnummer),
  Barn VARCHAR(11), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Barn) REFERENCES Person(Personnummer), 
  Förskola VARCHAR(50), 
    FOREIGN KEY (Förskola) REFERENCES Förskola(IDnr),
```

Please check that all 3 distinct columns are of same data type.

That means:

```
Handläggare(Anställningsnr) should be VARCHAR(50)
Person(Personnummer) should be VARCHAR(11)
Förskola(IDnr) should be VARCHAR(50).
```

As per me i think you are making a mistake in

```
Förskola(IDnr) should be VARCHAR(50)
```

which should have been a Number

Comment: They all have the same data type, and i have created several tables befor using them all as foregin key, just not in the same table... and im refering too the PERSON table, becuse Oracle points out that too be wrong.

Comment: Practically speaking that shouldnt be a problem. Try to remove one of the references in order to check if the problem persists...

if that works then we have faced a steel wall if not then we are making a mistake somewhere else...

Comment: That means your reference is wrong..check the data type of both columns. Also try to remove references one at a time thus singling out what reference is wrong...That way you would know the actual issue..

Comment: But how do you reference too a primary key twice in creating a table?